# Why won't the results of my form POST to another .php?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I've got a real simple html form:

```
<form action="emailform.php" method=post>
    <textarea name="emailBody"></textarea>
    <p>If you want a reply :</p>
    <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="emailSubmit" placeholder="Your Email">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submitButton">
</form>
```

And I'm just trying to get the inputs assigned to their respective variables in 'emailform.php', like this:

```
<?php
$email=$_REQUEST("userEmail");
print $email;
?>
```

As you can see I just tried it with one of the inputs, because I wasn't sure if the textarea works the same as a regular input, but even '$userEmail' doesn't seem to be getting the info as it doesn't print or echo anything.

I'm fairly new to this so this particular exercise is mostly for practice. In the end I don't want the submit button to redirect to another page, and I want the inputs emailed somewhere automatically, so if you can explain how to do that that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You use brackets, not parentheses, to access array values.

```
$email=$_REQUEST("userEmail");
```

should be:

```
$email=$_REQUEST["userEmail"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try the following, if you are trying to assign what the end user has input into the field.

You have put: 
    `$email = $_REQUEST("userEmail");`

I personally believe this would not be the best way to do this as you are using the PHP `POST` method in your form therefore you should use the `POST` method in your PHP code also like this:
    `$email = $_POST['userEmail'];`

`$_REQUEST` can be used for both `$_POST` and `$_GET`. But your are posting your information but if your are `GET`ting the users input then simply use `$_GET`
Try that and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the missing the quotes on `method="post"` in your form tag, try this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = $_POST['userEmail'];
    print $email;
} else {
 print "Oops, something went wrong."
} 
?>
```